# notation in Rudin's RCA Exercise 4.6.

Tags: real-analysis

In RCA Exercise 4.6, it says that $H$ is a Hilbert space, and $\{u_n \}$ is a orthonormal set in $H$. $S$ is a set of all $x \in H$ of the form $x=\sum_1 ^\infty c_n u_n $ (where $|c_n | \le \delta_n $ ). I have to prove that $S$ is compact iff $\sum _1 ^\infty \delta_n ^2 < \infty $. However, I don't get the notation $x=\sum_1 ^\infty c_n u_n $. How is this well-defined, for instance when $c_n = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb {N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (tacitly) assumed that $\sum_1^\infty \lvert c_n\rvert^2 < \infty$, so that the series converges in $H$. In full, the definition would be

$$S = \left\{ x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n u_n : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert c_n\rvert^2 < \infty\text{ and } \bigl(\forall n\bigr)\bigl( \lvert c_n\rvert \leqslant \delta_n\bigr)\right\}.$$